# why are video communication services from cloud so costly to be integrated in our websites?

Tags: twilio, azure-communication-services

I am developing a web application that also utilizes video and text chat services from cloud (looking for options like aws, azure, twilio...).
One thing I noticed was the cost. Its Huge to integrate and give it to customers. when there are applications like duo, skype that are free, why are these so costly (its difficult to reason my customers). Are there any good video call service to integrate (that works like google meet, duo, skype...) and chat services that are atleast reasonable with quality to be launched from India?

Murthy

Answer (score 1):

As Azure Communication Services (ACS) is tagged, I can speak a little bit to that and try my best to answer your questions from an ACS perspective.

To your first concern regarding pricing, please first check out the pricing page for ACS [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/overview). For example, a three person call with video over IP run out of the East US data center for 30 minutes would cost less than one USD.

Skype is a great product and even though it's a free consumer grade product, it still provides entry level security. There are certain features of the product though such a configuration of policies that cannot be done. Microsoft Teams, which is what ACS uses, provides enterprise configuration. This allows companies to lock down, secure, access user logs, storage of logs for compliance purposes, etc.

ACS allows you to take your Microsoft Teams experience and add additional features such as custom Teams integration into your company application, SMS client library allows you to send and receive SMS messages from your .NET and JavaScript applications, and other common scenarios, which can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/overview#common-scenarios).

ACS also provides chat functionality, which can be explored [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/chat/get-started?pivots=programming-language-csharp).

ACS has been in public preview since September 2020 and should be launching in General Availability (GA) in the coming weeks.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Applications like Duo and Meet (Google) or Skype (Microsoft) aren't necessarily financed by their users, but there is a cost to run those services and the owners of those services cover those costs or make them back in other ways.

When choosing to implement video calling from your own application, it is better to know and understand those costs up front and for you to decide how your application will finance them.

On behalf of Twilio, we have a few different options that might help you decide.

Firstly, we do provide a free service, [Twilio WebRTC Go](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/tutorials/understanding-video-rooms#video-webrtc-go-rooms), which gives you the infrastructure and SDKs to provide peer-to-peer video calls for 2 participants at a time.

If you need more participants in a call, you can choose [Twilio Video P2P](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/tutorials/understanding-video-rooms#video-p2p-rooms), which is still peer-to-peer, includes unlimited TURN data and only costs 0.0015c per participant per minute. For the 30 minute call between 3 people that Bryan mentioned, this would cost less than 20 cents.

Finally, if you need more participants, video recording, dominant speaker detection, connection to phone calls, and advanced bandwidth profile, track subscription and network quality APIs, you can choose [Twilio Video Group Rooms](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/tutorials/understanding-video-rooms#video-group-rooms), which still only cost 0.004c per participant per minute but come with all the features that a central media server can offer.

As for chat, check out the [Twilio Conversations API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/api) ([pricing details here](https://www.twilio.com/conversations/pricing)).

I recommend you try getting started with Twilio WebRTC Go, which is free, and see how you get on. Any other questions, do feel free to get in touch.